# How does the APP Advanced setting relate to the version and version of My Program?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I use Facebook login service. How does the version in the `API Version Upgrades` section of the App `Administration> Dashboard> Settings> Advanced Settings` menu affect users logging in via Facebook? Even if I use the latest version in my program, can I be affected if the settings are as above? Thank you.

Comment: You can simply overwrite the API version that is specified in the actual requests using those options. Not sure what you mean by how it “affects” users - well it makes the API calls against that specified version, not sure how that could be expressed any more plainly …

Answer (score 0):

Changing the API version will upgrade (or downgrade) the endpoint version used and may break your existing code if you use any functionality that had been deprecated between different versions.

You can use the [Upgrade Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/api_versioning/) to see affected functionality between versions.